# Get different kind of entries relatedTo one asset (many to one)?

Tags: relations, entries-field

I got an asset field called `docs` which is contained in 2 different entries.
Those entries are in different sections and they contain the `docs` field **directly** or through a **matrix** field called `articleBody`.

I made two queries relatedTo and merge them thereafter.
It works but would it be a better way by combining the two queries in one **relatedTo** call?

Query 1: `pages` section entries contain `docs` field inside a matrix field called `articleBody`
Query 2: `library` section entries contain `docs` field directly

```
        $criteria1 = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
        $criteria1->section = 'pages';
        $criteria1->relatedTo = array(
            'targetElement' => $asset->id,
            'field' => 'articleBody.docs'
        );

        $criteria2 = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
        $criteria2->section = 'library';
        $criteria2->relatedTo = array(
            'targetElement' => $asset->id,
            'field' => 'docs'
        );

        $criteria = array_merge($criteria1, $criteria2);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK in fact it was very simple: criteria params accept arrays...

```
        $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);

        $fields = [
            'articleBody.efficyDocuments',
            'efficyDocuments'
        ];

        $criteria->relatedTo = array(
            'targetElement' => $asset->id,
            'field' => $fields,
        );
```